# caffe net get next batch from hdf5 layer

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe, hdf5, pycaffe

I'm using Caffe's Python interface to test my trained network:

```
model_def = "./test.prototxt"
model_weights = "./seg_10000.caffemodel" # contains trained weights

net = caffe.Net(model_def, model_weights, caffe.TEST)    
output = net.forward()
```

This works for only the first image. My "test.prototxt" file loads data from the hdf5 format and contains 20 images:

```
layer { top: "data" top: "label" name: "loaddata" type: "HDF5Data" hdf5_data_param { source: "/home/mmc/data.txt" batch_size: 1 } include { phase: TEST } }
```

The `data.txt` file points to a .h5 file that contains 20 images i.e. `20x3x100x100`.

However, when I print the shape of the "data" blob, I only see one image.

`net.blobs["data"].data.shape` comes out to be `1x3x100x100`

Could the batch_size parameter be messing with it? Or is there a different way to initialize the network?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data layer you defined uses `batch_size: 1` this means your net processes one image at a time *regardless of the number of images in the test set*. If you want it to read all 20 images at once, you need to define the `batch_size` of the data layer to be 20.

Comment: My `train.prototxt` also has `batch_size: 1`. Does that mean it's training on only one image? What is the point of the `batch_size` parameter then? I thought it was just for performance reasons.